# PHP How can I iterate over a directory and merge all files that end with same string in a single file of that name

Tags: php, csv

**Description:**

I have a directory that contains a large number of files named as follows:

```
2013_11_weekly.csv 
2013_10_weekly.csv 
2013_08_weekly.csv 
2013_09_weekly.csv 
2013_11_any_string.csv 
2013_10_any_string.csv
```

**Problem:**

How can I iterate over the directory and merge all the files that end with the same string into single files?

The end result would be a directory containing the following files.

```
weekly.csv 
any_string.csv 
...
```

**Research:**

I have the following code snippet that merges all all files.

```
<?php

$files = glob("*.csv");
$out = fopen("merged_files.csv", "w");
foreach($files as $file){
    fwrite($out, file_get_contents($file));
}
fclose($out);
echo "files merged";

?>
```

How can I amend my script to achieve the above?

I know I may have to use an array function, a `str_` function and possibly a regular expression function.

Comment: If substring x last chars == "weekly.csv" [...] Look for substr

Comment: Substr will work if the "date" prefix is always the same number of characters - otherwise you need to look for some kind of separator (e.g. the second '_' character) and compare strings from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple, you must just figure out, how to fetch common name from filenames.

In my example, I split filename on 8th position (`2013_11_weekly.csv` becomes `weekly.csv` ):

```php
$files = glob("*.csv");
$out = array();
foreach($files as $file) {
    $name = substr(basename($file), 8);
    if (!isset($out[$name])) {
        $out[$name] = fopen($name, "w");
    }
    fwrite($out[$name], file_get_contents($file));
}
foreach ($out as $f) {
    fclose($f);
}
```

Comment: Glavic Thank you for this answer I had some good answers on this question,  my skill level is not good enough in php to say which answer is better or worse. I chose your answer because it worked first time, it used the language same level of language I used in my question so I could easily understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this - it assumes the rules to grouping files (2013_[two-digits]_[grouping_string]).
Nice trick is using ?P sign in regexp, which will put the aggregation string into $maches array under 'string_aggr' key:

```
$filenameRegexp = '/2013_[0-9]{2}_(?P<string_aggr>.+)\.csv/';
foreach (glob('*.csv') as $filename) {
   if (preg_match($filenameRegexp, $filename, $matches)) {
      $aggrFilename = $matches['string_aggr'] '.csv';
      file_put_contents($aggrFilename, file_get_contents(filename), FILE_APPEND);
   }
}
```

What it does is basically:

1. Find all files matching the pattern '*.csv';
2. Take each file and check if it matches pattern "2013_[two-digits]_[anything].csv"
3. If it does match the pattern - get it's contents, and append it to
   the end of the file named "anything.csv".

After running it you should get desired results - multiple files with aggregated contents, according to those "anything" parts, in your case: weekly, any_string etc.

Comment: This is the most generic (maybe the best?) solution, but also the most hard to understand, because of the matchers... They are pretty tough stuff for beginners...

Comment: This regex doesn't add any value, than a simple string cut on 8th position.

Comment: @Glavić it's true, but a regex can be modified and it will still be working, if the rule does not depend on string length.

Comment: String cutting can also be modified and it will still be working ;) Answer to current question is very simple string operation. You could also fix that it will work for all years, not only 2013. `?P<...>` works without that `P` part. **[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/zG1bK6)**

Comment: Thank you for your answer I found it very helpful for my learning I haven't used it because it used 2013 and I actually have  files that go back to 1973 though and always try to use generic code where possible, unfortunately beginers like me are still struggling regex's.

Comment: Use this regex then :) '/[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{2}_(?P<string_aggr>.+)\.csv/'

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful for you. If you not getting your proper answer than let me know. [merging multiple csv files using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082877/merging-multiple-csv-files-using-php)

Comment: Thanks for answer however I have recieved some good answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an array, concatenate all values into array and then create those files

For example :

```
$files = glob("*.csv");
$files_content = array();

//parse all your files
foreach($files as $file){
    //get the suffix (ie '_weekly')
    $filename_end = substr(basename($file), 8);
    if(!isset($files_content[$file])) $files_content[$file] = "";
    //concatenate strings
    $files_content[$file] .= file_get_contents($file);
}

//and then create those files
foreach($fields_content as $filename => $content){
    $out = fopen($filename, "w");
    fwrite($out, $content);
    fclose($out);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, yours was the answer I first tried, however I  changed this line to foreach($fields_content as $filename => $content){, to foreach($files_content as $filename => $content){ and it worked unfortunately on many webhosting servers there is a memory limit of about 100mb for large files so I when I ran the script I got the following error Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 14518528 bytes) in. To resolve this error in the  past I have had to rewrite my scripts to read a line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fwrite, you should use [file_put_content](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).
This function is able to append data to a file.

> **Description**
>
> int file_put_contents ( string $filename , mixed $data [,
>   int $flags = 0 [, resource $context ]] )
>
> This function is identical to calling fopen(), fwrite() and fclose()
>   successively to write data to a file.
>
> If filename does not exist, the file is created. Otherwise, the
>   existing file is overwritten, unless the FILE_APPEND flag is set.

resulting in code like (not tested, just for understanding):

```
<?php
$files = glob("*.csv");
foreach($files as $file){
    // get substring 6 chars before the last 4 chars (.csv)
    $type = substr($file, -4, -10)
    // switch based on the substring $type
    switch($type) {
        case "weekly":
            file_put_content("merged_files_weekly.csv", file_get_contents($file), FILE_APPEND);
        break;
        case "string" :
            file_put_content("merged_any_string.csv", file_get_contents($file), FILE_APPEND);
        break;
        default:
            // do nothing
        break;
    }

}
echo "files merged";
```

Comment: Thanks for answer I literally have thousands of files so using case wasn't viable.